# How to build online xul application with spring 3?

Tags: spring, xul

Is there any modern example of building XUL web application with spring? What I found is only 1-2 years old, but already not working (trying to run them in firefox 8).

Answer (score 0):

There is a reason for that - starting with Firefox 4 remote XUL is [no longer supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_Remote_XUL), for security reasons. So using it for a new web application would be a bad decision, even if you are building an intranet application. It is better to build on HTML5.

Comment: Yes, i completely agree with you, that for modern web applications html5 is much better. Still i want to learn xul technology.

Comment: @KonstantinPetrukhnov: Then the link I gave you has the instructions on how to enable remote XUL. As to using it, nothing really changed in two years.